# Google Sheets: Select value in 2d table with range

Tags: google-sheets

Query: Year=4, Value=1700. Result=1.7

Value data: 0-1000, 1000-1500, 1500-1800 (query range), 1800-2300, 2300-3000, 3000-10000
[image]

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=+filter(choosecols(filter(C3:H;C2:H2>=K2);1);countifs(J2;">="&A3:A;J2;"<="&B3:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you. I maked mistake: Value=1700 in range (1500-1800), so it must return 1.7 ...

Comment: Are you able to modify the formula or need further help?!

Comment: I tryed get prev column (-1), but it returned last .. filter(C3:H4;C2:H2>=1700);-1)

Comment: Replace this part of the formula `choosecols(filter(C3:H;C2:H2>=K2);1)` with `=choosecols(filter(C3:H;C2:H2<=K2);-1)`